# Angular | Guard not firing on routerLink click

Tags: angular, service

I am trying to implement a guard for my routes which are for plugins.

I have the concept nailed for it and it does seem to work, however I am having 2 issues and they are as follows:

- When clicking on a `routerLink` from within the Angular app. It doesn't seem to call the guard at all and allows the user to navigate to the route.
- The other issue is that when the route is navigated to via the url e.g `/plugins/team-members` then the page will not redirect.

Here is my router module:

```
const routes = {
    path: 'plugin',
    canActivate: [
        BIPluginGuard
    ],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'team-members',
            component: BIPluginTeamMembers
        },
        {
            path: 'sponsors',
            component: BIPluginSponsors
        }
    ]
};
```

And here is my guard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        const currentRoute: string = route.children[0].routeConfig.path;

        const accessiblePlugin: any = this.plugins.find((plugin) => {
            return plugin.path === currentRoute;
        });

        if (!accessiblePlugin || !accessiblePlugin.allowed) {
            this.router.navigate['/dashboard'];
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This is my first time using a guard so I am unsure as to whether or not I have to put the `canActivate` on every route, I want to avoid that if possible though.

Comment: can you console log a few things `route.children[0].routeConfig.path` and `accessiblePlugin` and share the output?

Comment: Hi, accessible Plugin is a object which contains the path and whether the plugin is allowed. In this case false, and the path is `team-members`. The logic is correct, it's just not functioning properly

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon this issue myself and I have found a working solution for my scenario.

In your routing module you use: `canActivate`, and then you have a list of `children`.

When you want to use a guard on children of a path you need to use a different keyword. The correct one should be `canActivateChild`. This does mean you need to change your guard implements.

In the end you should have something like:

Routing module

```js
const routes = {
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: [
        ExampleGuard
    ],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'example',
            component: ExampleComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'example2',
            component: Example2Component
        }
    ]
};
```

ExampleGuard

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ExampleGuard implements CanActivateChild {
  canActivateChild(
    childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) on canActivate signature , consist of RouterStateSnapshot as the second parameter to the function.Can you try including that like this

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean
```

Also, check whether registered this route guard with app.module.ts under providers

Comment: This made no difference

Comment: ca you create a stackbiltz example the so that i can debug at my end?

Comment: also did you add this guard in the app module under providers? @tallent123

Comment: I did add it to the modules under provider yes. The guard is working, I am hitting the guard. I am getting there, it is fine other than not being able to stop the navigation etc. I cannot create a stack blitz as the project is too big in it's entirety and I cannot grab things out as they are part of a library.

Comment: what does the `plugin.path` and `currentRoute` values are?
 what i want to know is whether the guard is returning true or false correctly to start off with ,if the guard is getting hit and the value returned is also correct then we might see  for other places to pin point the isssue , hence to start i was asking for console log prints @tallent123

Answer (score 0):

Should the url `/plugins/team-members` be `/plugin/team-members`? Your route specifies the path as `path: 'plugin'` where plugin is singular.

Can you confirm the network tab in the developer tools isn't showing a 404 error for the request to team-members?

Comment: There is no 404 error on the developer network. It is returning a 304. The route is right and it's finding route but it's not doing as it should. The white page is when I am returning false and not redirecting.

Comment: Do you have a routeroutlet defined in the html as a target for this routerlink?

Comment: For the route guard, I see the guard function defined as canActivate, but the route canActivate is set to BIPluginGuard. Is that the file name? Wrap the function name in apostrophes

Comment: What do you mean, I am failing to understand?

Comment: A routerlink requires a place to be displayed. That is in a <routeroutlet></routeroutlet>. The browser doesn't load everything from the server like a traditional <a></a>. When routerlink is used the component in the route displays its template or templateurl in the routeroutlet but the page doesn't refresh.